# admob Mail PIN issues "There were problems sending your form. Please try again." Can't send address verifying form

Tags: forms, admob, verification

I requested a pin 3 times, but I did not receive a letter to my address. I think the reason for not coming is due to covid-19. Later the form link was opened(Contact Support). I get an error after filling out the form. "There were problems sending your form. Please try again."

[image: screenshot]